# Xamarin - How do I inject a property into a ContentView from the ContentPage or ContentPageViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding

*Update:* I've updated this a bit to remove the reference to the error. @michal-diviš gave the correction solution to that. However, my larger issue still remains.

---

I'm new to Xamarin and trying to learn by making a simple email client. I'm trying to set a property on a ContentPage I have created.

### The Setup

The MainPage simply has a grid with two columns; the left side features an CollectionView of the inbox, the right side is my custom ContentPage `MessageDisplayView`. When an email is clicked in the CollectionView, the `CurrentMessage` property on the `MainPageViewModel` is updated to the selected item.

### The Issue

I'm trying to bind the property `MessageDisplayView.Message` to the `MainPageViewModel.CurrentMessage` property, but the contentpage never updates. I've tried with and without BindableProperty, as well as other ideas found while searching Google and Stackoverflow.

### The Question

**How do I handle setting and updating a property that I would like to live with the ContentPage?**

### The Code

*MainPage.xaml*

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:c="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Project.View"
             xmlns:fa="clr-namespace:FontAwesome"
             x:Class="Project.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/EmailResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="MainPageGrid">

    <!-- other xaml code -->

        <view:MessageDisplayView
            x:Name="MyDisplayView"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Message="{Binding CurrentMessage}"  <!-- Error -->
            />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

*MainPageViewModel.cs*

```cs
using MimeKit;
using Project.EmailLogic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Project.ViewModel
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public class MainPageViewModel: ObservableObject
    {

            private MimeMessage currentMessage;

            public MimeMessage CurrentMessage
            {
                get => currentMessage; 
                set => SetProperty(ref currentMessage, value, nameof(MessageDisplayView.Message));
            }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

*MessageDisplayView.xaml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Project.View" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModel" 
             x:DataType="view:MessageDisplayView"
             xmlns:fa="clr-namespace:FontAwesome"
             x:Class="Project.View.MessageDisplayView">

  <ContentView.Content>
      <Grid>

        <!-- Various standard xaml things, for example... -->
            <!-- Subject Line -->
            <Label x:Name="SubjectLine"
                Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding Message.Subject}"
                />

        </Grid>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

*MessageDisplayView.xaml.cs*

```cs
using MimeKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Project.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MessageDisplayView : ContentView
    {
        private MimeMessage message;
        public MimeMessage Message
        {
            get
            {
                return (MimeMessage)GetValue(MessageProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MessageProperty, value);
                BodyHtmlViewSource.Html = Message.HtmlBody;
            }
        }

        public BindableProperty MessageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Message), typeof(MimeMessage), typeof(MessageDisplayView));

        public HtmlWebViewSource BodyHtmlViewSource { get; set; }

        public MessageDisplayView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you bind the property MessageDisplayView.Message to the MainPageViewModel.CurrentMessage property still failed? If it's successful, what's your problem now?

Comment: The problem was that `MessageDisplayView` was not being notified of the update, which I thought was the whole point of Binding them in the xaml. I found a solution last night, which uses information from @michal-diviš answer, but placed in the proper class. I have added a fix below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the BindableObject was not hearing the notifications of the property changing.

The solution was to add the `OnPropertyChanged` method to the code behind of the `ContentView`, not the `ContentPageViewModel`.

This "solution" correctly updates the property in the code, but it *does not* update the xaml/UI. I think this might a separate issue.

---

This confused me at first, when @michal-diviš pointed out the `OnPropertyChanged` calls, as I thought I was suppose to wire up the event subscription myself in the ContentView code behind. But after stumbling across [this article](https://www.mfractor.com/blogs/news/custom-controls-in-xamarin-forms), I realized that the method was required elsewhere.

I feel like a major issue is that there isn't a lot of information about passing data or properties between elements/UserControls/ContentPages, etc. Over the last two days, I've read and watched a fair amount on BindableProperties, but seen very little use of OnPropertyChanged or updating the properties from elsewhere. Perhaps I'm missing the places where it's talked about, or maybe it's more easy or obvious than I realize, but in hindsight, this seems like something that should have been mentioned in every BindableProperty 101.

Beyond the official documentation of course, if anyone knows a good article or video going over sharing/binding/updating properties between classes/views/whatever, I'd love to check that out.

Here's an example of the final, working code:

```cs
    public partial class MessageDisplayView : ContentView
    {
        public MimeMessage Message
        {
            get
            {
                return (MimeMessage)GetValue(MessageProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MessageProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static BindableProperty MessageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Message), typeof(MimeMessage), typeof(MessageDisplayView), new MimeMessage(),
                BindingMode.TwoWay);

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == MessageProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                if(Message != null)
                {
                    // Update ContentView properties and elements.
                }
            }
        }
```

**Thank you again to @michal-diviš for your help!**

Answer (score 1):

## Fix

It's the `BindableProperty` definition!
You have (in the *MessageDisplayView.xaml.cs*):

```cs
public BindableProperty MessageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Message), typeof(MimeMessage), typeof(MessageDisplayView));
```

you need to make it `static readonly` like this:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty MessageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Message), typeof(MimeMessage), typeof(MessageDisplayView));
```

## Usage of INotifyPropertyChanged

The `CurrentMessage` property in your `MainPageViewModel` seems to be the problem. You've created it as a `BindableProperty`, however, that's meant to be used by user controls, not view models.

What you need in the view model is to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and invoke the `PropertyChanged` event in the property setter. That is done so the UI will update itseld whenever the `CurrentMessage` property changes.

Tweak your *MainViewModel.cs* like this:

```cs
using MimeKit;
using Project.EmailLogic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Project.ViewModel
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private MimeMessage currentMessage;
        public MimeMessage CurrentMessage
        {
            get => currentMessage;
            set {
                currentMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentMessage))
            };
        }
        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In this example, I've implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly in you view model, but a better way to do it is to inherit from a base class that already has that implemented, like this one: [ObservableObject from James Montemagno's MVVM Helpers library](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/master/MvvmHelpers/ObservableObject.cs). The resulting view model would look like this:

```cs
using MimeKit;
using Project.EmailLogic;
using MvvmHelpers;

namespace Project.ViewModel
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private MimeMessage currentMessage;
        public MimeMessage CurrentMessage
        {
            get => currentMessage;
            set => SetProperty(ref currentMessage, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Lately I've been using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) library instead of Refactored.MvvmHelpers as it's more updated and feature rich.

Comment: Unfortunately, that hasn't fixed the error. Though I am glad you helped with the PropertyChange calls, as that was the next thing I was going to start looking into.

For further clarification, the error comes from building, so I am unable to even run the app, let alone catch property changes yet.

A UserControl should be able to bind to a property on the parent's ViewModel, right?

Comment: @Michael I've updated the answer. I've managed to make it work. You need to make the `BindableProperty` `static`...

Comment: @Michael If my answer helped you, please consider hitting the upvote (up arrow) button. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @michal-diviš, this has definitely solved the error, thank you. I've marked it as the correct answer, but I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote.

Now, I need to figure out how to get the user control to register the change of the property. I've impliemented Jame's ObservableObject, I thought by "binding" the properties, they would always be in sync...?

Comment: Is the UserControl suppose to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event...? It's all bound to the property, shouldn't it just automatically update?

Comment: @Michael you don't need to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event. Xamarin should do that automatically. The only thing you need to do is use binding in the UI like so: `<Label Text="{Binding CurrentMessage.Subject}" />`. That's all it takes to have the data update in the UI automatically. Definitely do not subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event anywhere in your code (it's not illegal, but it shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: Oh, this comment was hidden from me as I was typing my solution below. --- 

The way you've just described is how I had it set up already (as you can see in the original code), but it wasn't working. That is how I EXPECTED it to work, but it didn't. I ended up having to add the OnPropertyChanged method to the `ContentView`, which now manually updates the elements. Though, it's not the ideal way to handle it, in my opinion. --- Is it possible the Binding doesn't automatically update because the Type is not set up or registered or [I don't know the right wording] to be used like this?

Comment: If you'd like to add the code snippet with `OnPropertyChanged` in the `MessageDisplayView` class, I'll mark your answer as the correct answer, as you've definitely given a lot of helpful information beyond even the initial problem.