# Binding in XAML ContentView does not update UI (ie Label) in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, binding

##### Preamble

I have read many other questions here about this problem, but none solved my problem.

I also recently [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971158/xamarin-how-do-i-inject-a-property-into-a-contentview-from-the-contentpage-or/70971261) about getting the property on the ContentView to be updated from the parent ContentPage. That is resolved, and I am certain the Property on the ContentView code behind is updating as intended.

---

### The Problem

While using a custom ContentView `MessageDisplayView`, the elements in my XAML (ie: Label, WebView) do not update to match their bound properties in the code behind.

##### Situation

I have one BindableProperty `Message` of type MIME (email data object). This property is set when the ContentView is used on a ContentPage `<view:MessageDisplayView x:Name="ReadingPane" Message="{Binding CurrentMessage}"/>`. This works correctly.

In my ContentView `MessageDisplayView`, I have several Labels and one WebView. I have tried binding these elements to different things, but the UI is never updated.

I have tried:

- Binding a label to a string property of `Message`, ie: `<Label x:Name="FromDisplay" Text="{Binding Message.From[0].Name}" />`
- Binding a label to it's own property, ie: `<Label x:Name="ToDisplay" Text="{Binding ToName}" />`
- Binding a label to a property that also has a BindableProperty accompanying it. (same code as above)
- I have also made sure to try calling `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ToName));`, as well as the one called for `Message`.

The only that will work, is if when `OnPropertyChanged` is called for Message, I manually update the Label text. But I don't want this. I would prefer if the code behind never dealt with the xaml/view.

I have verified that all the properties in the code behind are being updated correctly. The Intellisense works in xaml, allowing me to fill in the correct properties. Why does the UI never update to reflect the changes?

##### Code

*The ConentView `MessageDisplayView.xaml`*

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:view="clr-Project.View" 
             x:DataType="view:MessageDisplayView"
             x:Class="Project.View.MessageDisplayView">


  <ContentView.Content>
      <Grid>

            <!-- Subject Line -->
            <Label x:Name="SubjectLine"
                Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding Message.Subject}"
                />
          
            <!-- To/From/Date -->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="2"
                >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label
                        Text="From:"
                        />
                    <Label
                        x:Name="FromDisplay"
                        Text="{Binding FromName}"
                        />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label
                        Text="To:"
                        />
                    <Label
                        x:Name="ToDisplay"
                        Text="{Binding ToName}"
                        />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>



            <!-- Body -->
            <WebView x:Name="BodyDisplay"
                Grid.Row="3"
                     BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                     Source="{Binding BodyHtmlViewSource}"
                />


        </Grid>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

*The ConentView `MessageDisplayView.xaml.cs`*

```cs
using MimeKit;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Project.View
{
    public partial class MessageDisplayView : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string FromName { get; set; }

        public string ToName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(ToNameProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ToNameProperty, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ToName));
            }
        }

        public static BindableProperty ToNameProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ToName), typeof(string), typeof(MessageDisplayView), "Default To Field",
                BindingMode.TwoWay);


        public MimeMessage Message
        {
            get
            {
                return (MimeMessage)GetValue(MessageProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MessageProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static BindableProperty MessageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Message), typeof(MimeMessage), typeof(MessageDisplayView), new MimeMessage(),
                BindingMode.TwoWay);


        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == MessageProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                if(Message != null)
                {
                    FromName = Message.From[0].ToString();
                    ToName = Message.To[0].Name;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ToName));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FromName));
                    //SubjectLine.Text = Message.Subject;    <--Manually setting does work (when uncommented)
                }
            }
        }

        public MessageDisplayView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ToName = "This is a test name";   <-- I never see this
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

**UPDATE**

*The ContentPage `MainPage.xaml`*

```xml
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:c="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Project.View"
             xmlns:fa="clr-namespace:FontAwesome"
             x:Class="Project.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


    <Grid x:Name="MainPageGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Unrelated Code -->

        <view:MessageDisplayView x:Name="ReadingPane"
                Grid.Column="1"
                IsVisible="{Binding DisplayReadingPane}"
                Message="{Binding CurrentMessage}"
                />


    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

- The ContentPage ViewModel `MainPageViewModel.cs`

```cs
namespace Project.ViewModel
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        #region Variables

            private ObservableCollection<MimeMessage> currentBox;
            public ObservableCollection<MimeMessage> CurrentBox
            {
                get
                {
                    if (currentBox == null)
                        currentBox = new ObservableCollection<MimeMessage>();
                    return currentBox;
                }
            }


            private MimeMessage currentMessage;
            public MimeMessage CurrentMessage
            {
                get => currentMessage;
                set
                {
                    SetProperty(ref currentMessage, value, nameof(CurrentMessage));
                }
            }

        public static BindableProperty CurrentMessageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CurrentMessage), typeof(MimeMessage), typeof(MainPageViewModel), new MimeMessage(), BindingMode.TwoWay);

    }
}
```

- MainPageViewModel base class `ObservableObject`*

```cs
namespace Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.ObjectModel
{

    public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly DelegateWeakEventManager weakEventManager = new DelegateWeakEventManager();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged
        {
            add
            {
                weakEventManager.AddEventHandler(value, "PropertyChanged");
            }
            remove
            {
                weakEventManager.RemoveEventHandler(value, "PropertyChanged");
            }
        }
        protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = "", Action? onChanging = null, Action? onChanged = null, Func<T, T, bool>? validateValue = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (validateValue != null && !validateValue!(backingStore, value))
            {
                return false;
            }

            onChanging?.Invoke();
            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = "")
        {
            weakEventManager.RaiseEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName), "PropertyChanged");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use the mvvm, you should obey the rules. You cann't make your view extend the INotifyPropertyChanged which should be extended by the viewmodel.

Comment: Okay, I'm still learning this. To be clear, and to understand better, I have two scripts inheriting INotifyPropertyChanged: 1) the code behind for the ConentView, `MessageDisplayView`, and; 2) the view model for the ContentPage, `MainPageViewModel`. Obviously, the latter is not the view model for the former. So, since they are for different scripts and different elements, are they not allowed to both use INotifyPropertyChanged? Or is that still breaking the rule?

Comment: In the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#summary), the view can have its own binding context. So the collection view can set the collect viewmodel and the page can set the page viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at the link and see if I can find the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - i can't see where you set the message, but i changed your code a bit. I don't think you want all that inside the OnPropertyChanged method.. You could give it a try:

```
 public partial class MessageDisplayView : ContentView, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FromName { get; set; }

    public string ToName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(ToNameProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ToNameProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ToName));
        }
    }

    public static BindableProperty ToNameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ToName), typeof(string), typeof(MessageDisplayView), "Default To Field",
            BindingMode.TwoWay);


    public MimeMessage Message
    {
        get
        {
            return (MimeMessage)GetValue(MessageProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MessageProperty, value);
            if (value is MimeMessage message) 
            {
                FromName = message.From[0].ToString();
                ToName = message.To[0].Name;

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ToName));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FromName));
            }

        }
    }

    public static BindableProperty MessageProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Message), typeof(MimeMessage), typeof(MessageDisplayView), new MimeMessage(),
            BindingMode.TwoWay);


    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public MessageDisplayView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ToName = "This is a test name";  // < --I never see this
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. (I'd already tried it, not sure why I wasn't in my example; perhaps I tried after positing.). The problem is that when I declare that `BindingContext = this`, the ContentView does not receive updates from the parent/ContentPage anymore. Without that property from the ContentPage, there is nothing to change ContentView.

Comment: Could the problem be that there are two BindingContexts needed? All the elements on the ContentView either directly bind to the code behind's `MessageDisplayView.Message` or to other properties that rely on `Message`. However, `Message` is bound to the `ContentPage.CurrentMessage` property in the main ViewModel.

Comment: I don't think so. If you set a breakpoint in the setter of MimeMessage - is it ever invoked?

Comment: Well, this is weird. The setter for `MessageDisplayView.Message` never hits the breakpoint, regardless of the BindingContext. However, if BindingContext is not set, it will trigger the OnPropertyChanged method, including the `if (propertyName == MessageProperty.PropertyName)`. Also, I can tell that `Message` is being updated properly. But the Setter is never triggered.

Comment: It would be easier i we could see how the Message was set, but i think this is the issue. Are you calling OnPropertyChanged(<nameofmessageproperty>) from your binding context?

Comment: I was using Montemagno's ObservableObject base class on the ContentPage/MainPage, but have recently switched to the CommunityToolkit version. Of course, it does the same thing, and none of it seems to affect the ContentView. -- I've updated the post to include code from the ContentPage `MainPage`.